# How can I insert xml data (as variable) from PHP using XSLT

Tags: php, xml, xslt

I have a requirement of generating a master XML file by integrating some XML files. It can be achieved if we have different child XML files stored at some where on the disk. But here in my case child XML files are dynamic XML data. They are not stored any where but generating dynamically. So how can i insert these child XML data to generate a master XML file.

My input is :

```
<root>
  <element id="1">
  </element>
  <element id="2">
  </element>
</root>
```

My output would be:

```
<root>
   <element id="1">
      <section>
         <record>12</record>
      </section>
   </element>
   <element id="2">
      <section>
          <input>menu</input>
      </section>
   </element>
</root>
```

Here in the above output XML data(`<section><record>12</record></section>`) should come from PHP variable.

Comment: You have to pass the two "dynamic" XML documents as parameters to the transformation. Read your XSLT processor documentation to learn what API to use for passing external parameters to a transformation.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to pass the two "dynamic" XML documents as parameters to the transformation**.

Each of the "dynamic documents" should be already parsed as an XML document (in other XSLT processor APIs there is a method  -- for example `XmlDocument.LoadXml()` --  that takes a string and parses it as XML and creates a (parsed) XML document).

Read your XSLT processor documentation to learn what API to use for passing external parameters to a transformation

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Can you explain with some example for above scenario.

Comment: @user806444: I don't know PHP. Are you interested in an example using C# and the .NET XslCompiledTransform XSLT processor?

Comment: Yes i am interested to see the code in even C#. I have done it in php. But in the output i got data with xml tags in the output. how can i display the xml file with out xml tags? Please help me out.

Comment: @user806444: just have: `<xsl:apply-templates select="$pDoc//text()"/>`

Comment: I am getting transformation warnings, if i use <xsl:apply-templates select="$pDoc//text()"/>

Comment: What kind of warnings? I recommend that you post this as a separate, new question.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread, but no satisfying answer has been given; recently I was confronted with a similar situation and I believe the solution is general enough to apply to problems like this one.

Essentially: PHP and the XSLT processor communicate via `DOMNode` objects (parameters and return values). Therefore, it is possible to construct a `DOMNode` object using PHP, returning it at the request of the XSLT processor.

Given the above example, we would have the following XSLT:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
                xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="element" />
    </root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="element">
    <element>
      <!-- Pass the selected id attributes to a PHP callback,
           then literally include the XML as returned from PHP.
           Alternatively, one could use xsl:apply-templates
           to further transform the result. -->
      <xsl:copy-of select="php:function('xslt_callback', @id)" />
    </element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the PHP function (this function should be exporteded with the `registerPHPFunctions` method [[see php manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php)]) would be:

```php
/**
 * @param  DOMAttr[]  $attr_set An array of DOMAttr objects,
 *                              passed by the XSLT processor.
 * @return DOMElement           The XML to be inserted.
 */
function xslt_callback ($attr_set) {
  $id = $attr_set[0]->value;
  return new DOMElement('section', $id); //whatever operation you fancy
}
```

Resulting in the following XML:

```xml
<root>
  <element>
    <section>1</section>
  </element>
  <element>
    <section>2</section>
  </element>
</root>
```

The php function `xslt_callback` can do whatever it likes with the selected id. We assume in this example that `$attr_set` always contains exactly one selected attribute. Depending on the situation, it might be advisable to perform some range or type checking; here however, this would only needlessly complicate the example skeleton.

Note: simply returning an XML string from PHP would result in `&lt;` and `&gt;` tags to be inserted for every `<` and `>`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still wondering what you wanted from php
I assumed that you could reprint and throw something like the following in a loop but I'm happy to dig further to the point of making something website front end with dynamic xml generation. Changing in this page what scalors option does by switching values is distinct in php there's lots that could be done please tell me further what you Want

```
<?php
$i=1;
$option = "default";
$elemental = 1;
$StrRecord = "12";
$StrInput = "menu";
$domdoc = new DOMDocument();
$domdoc->preserveWhiteSpaces = false;
$domdoc->load(realpath('xmlfile.xml'));
$root = new DOMElement('root');
$element = new DOMElement('element');
$section = new DOMElement('section');
$record = new DOMElement('record', $StrRecord);
$elementi = new DOMElement('element');
$sectioni = new DOMElement('section');
$inputi = new DOMElement('input', $StrInput);
$elementid= new DOMAttr('id', $elemental+1);
$elementidi= new DOMAttr('id', $elemental+1);

$domdoc->appendChild($root);
$root->appendChild($element);
$element->appendChild($section);
$section->appendChild($record);
$root->appendChild($elementi);
$elementi->appendChild($sectioni);
$sectioni->appendChild($inputi);
$sectioni->appendChild($inputi);
$element->appendChild($elementid);
$elementi->appendChild($elementidi);
$domdoc->formatOutput = true;
$domdoc->save('xmlfile.xml');

$xmldoc= new DOMDocument();
$xmldoc->load(realpath('xmlfile.xml'));
$xpath = new DOMXpath($xmldoc);

switch($option){
case "record":
$query = ('/root/element/section/record');
break;
case "input":
$query = ('/root/element/section/input');
break;
case "default":
$query = ('/root/element[@id="'. $i.'"]/');
break;
}
$nodeList = $xpath->query($query);
foreach($nodeList as $node){
echo($node->nodeValue);
}
?>
```